# Can I deploy to App Store Connect without Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles privileges?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Can I deploy to App Store Connect, or send .ipa file without invitation on their Account? Also if they invites me as Developer/App Manager, can I deploy(send .ipa file) without Profile and Certificates privilege?

Comment: Refer to https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve5f9a89d7 with the developer role you can submit builds as long as all of the configuration is in place (certificates, app definition, profiles). If you want to do everything then you will need the app manager role and access to profiles and certificates.

Comment: Thank you! But to be more specified, if I have personal Account, and they didn't invite me to their account. But just send me Distribution and Profile cert, can I generate .ipa file for their account?

Comment: If they give you their signing keys and the profile then you can generate an ipa file. You will need to deliver the ipa file to them so that they can upload to App Store Connect.

Comment: Thanks so much @Paulw11. The .ipa file successfully generated with out Team member invitation, just with iOS Distribution, and Profile Provision Certs.